# Node JS - child_process spawn('npm install') in Grunt task results in ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm having some difficulty with a Grunt task I'm authoring.  I'm trying to execute npm install, followed by bower install, followed by a grunt hub target (to trigger a build command for multiple sub-projects).

The problem I'm encountering lies with child_process.  I get spawn ENOENT error if I run the following commands in my grunt task, with the npm install spawn command that's currently commented out:

```
    var path = require('path'),
        projectPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), this.data.activity );

        grunt.log.debug('project path computed as: ', projectPath);
        process.chdir( projectPath );

        console.log('current dir is: ', process.cwd());
        console.log('EVN is: ', process.env);

        var spawnProcess = spawn('ls');
        // var spawnProcess = spawn('npm install');

        spawnProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('' + data);
        });

        spawnProcess.stderr.on('data', function(data) {

            console.log('something went wrong installing deps for ' + path + '.  Error: ', data);
        });

        spawnProcess.on('close', function (exitCode) {

            console.log( 'ls has finished with Exit Code: ' + exitCode);
        });
```

the current code (with ls instead of npm install) results in:

```
   running "install:projects" (install) task[D] Task source: /Users/zedd45/proj/Gruntfile.js
Verifying property install.projects exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
[D] project path computed as:  /Users/zedd45/proj/activity/web/client
current dir is:  /Users/zedd45/proj/activity/web/client
EVN (abbreviated) is:  { 
   TERM_PROGRAM: 'iTerm.app',
   SHELL: '/bin/bash',
   PWD: '/Users/zedd45/proj',
 ...
  OLDPWD: '/Users/zedd45/proj/activity/web/client',
  _: '/usr/local/bin/grunt' }

GruntFile.js
bower.json
package.json
this_is_the_directory_you_are_looking_for.txt
ls has finished with Exit Code: 0
```

but if I change 'ls' to 'npm install' I get instead 
``Fatal error: spawn ENOENT

immediately following the ENV print.

I have tried chmod 777 for that directory, which doesn't seem to help.

I have also tried:

```
// var spawnProcess = spawn('npm install', {'cwd': projectPath});
```

and

```
// var spawnProcess = spawn('npm install', [], {'cwd': projectPath});
```

The former results in

> Warning: Object # has no method 'slice' Use --force to
>   continue.

the later still results in the ENOENT error.

Any help with exactly what this ENOENT error is would probably help a great deal; I haven't had much success with Googling it nor with the [child process API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Double check the docs on child_process.spawn again. The first argument should be *only* the command to run and the second is the arguments:

```
var npm = spawn('npm', ['install'], { cwd: projectPath });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I can't believe how easy / obvious the solution was once you provided it, or how hard it eluded me.  Thanks so much!

Comment: for future reference of possible visitors, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-to-debug-any-node-js-child-process-error-spawn-enoent

Comment: Hmm, this didn't work for me. Still getting a spawnSync npm ENOENT (yes I'm using the sync version)

Comment: On Windows you need to call `npm.cmd`.