# NodeJs script with child_process spawn on Windows, why I need 'shell: true' for ENOENT error?

Tags: node.js, shell, cmd, child-process, spawn

I'm using this code:

```
const {
  spawn
} = require('child_process');

let info = spawn('npm', ["-v"]);

info.on('close', () => {
  console.log('closed');
}
```

But I have this error:

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:189:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:366:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

If I use instead:

```
let info = spawn('npm', ["-v"], {shell: true});
```

**it works!**

But why I need `shell: true`? I need also to see the stdout of that spawn, so I'm also using this:

```
let info = spawn('npm', ["-v"], {shell: true, stdio: 'inherit'});
```

It's correct?

Answer (score 4):

While calling spawn itself, there is no `npm` command under spawn. Thus you got that error message. Instead of using spawn itself, while adding `shell: true`, spawn will use **shell** of your system to run that command. Since your system has `npm`, it works.

> `let info = spawn('npm', ["-v"], {shell: true, stdio: 'inherit'});` It's correct?

The code is fine if your parameters of spawn are controllable. But generally, I suggest use pure spawn without using shell. The risk will reduce without touching shell directly.

---

Since you need the stream return from spawn. I have checked other solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156067/node-js-child-process-spawnnpm-install-in-grunt-task-results-in-enoent-err). `Without shell: true`, You can use the code:

```
const {
  spawn
} = require('child_process');

let projectPath = ''//the path of your project
let info = spawn('npm', ['-v'], { cwd: projectPath });

let result = '';
info.stdout.on('data', function(data) {  
  result += data.toString();
  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but I need the stdout "live" not at the end of my commands. How to with exec?

Comment: I got your reason of using spawn, have you tried cwd as a parameter? I have updated the code. Please give a try.

Comment: Is not working on windows the cwd. I tried every path mode: absolute, relative, back and forward slash. Nothing.